# Simplification: specific developmental disorders of school skills

Tags: alternatives

My friend asked me to translate her thesis synopsis into english. An original text was ugly and its translation is not better. Even it sound much worse:

> Bachelor thesis deals with the influence of specific developmental
>   disorders of school skills on human life. It contains a theoretical
>   overview of specific developmental disorders of school skills, their
>   diagnosis and communication area of individuals with these disorders.
>   The practical part presents four case studies showing the
>   communication difficulties of selected individuals and overcoming
>   them.

I am not sure if you understand this text. The thesis is about dyslexia and similar problems. How to simplify "specific developmental disorders of school skills" without loosing a meaning?

1. specific learning disorders
2. specific school skill development disorders
3. specific learning development disorders

Comment: Option 1 and 3 can be straightway ruled out as this is a research paper and I'm sure _learning disorders_ and _developmental disorders of school skills_ do not mean the same thing. Option 2 can be used if there exists a disorder named _school skill development disorder_ . Otherwise, you can use 'developmental disorders _related to_ school skills'.

Comment: I thought that learning and school skills are very similar.

Comment: In day to day language, maybe. But this is a technical paper. I'm not familiar with the technical terms used in psychology but I don't think you can change the name of a disorder as per your convenience :)

Comment: "School skills" has a particular meaning, encompassing the skills that make a student successful _in a **school setting.**_   This would include things like navigating from classroom to classroom, speaking up in large groups, maintaining a schedule planner, keeping track of books, taking notes, and so on. I doubt that is what you are studying.  Without knowing exactly what you _are_ studying, I can't suggest a better word, but school skills is almost certainly not it.  Your best bet is to find an article published by a native speaker on related topics and see what language they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At very least you could safely simplify the second occurrence. In the second sentence, replace *"specific developmental disorders of school skills"* with *"such skills"*.

But there are a few other things needing tidied up too.

- *"Bachelor thesis"* needs an article. e.g. *"This Bachelor thesis"*, or even better *"This Bachelor's thesis"*
- *"...and communication area of individuals..."* is wrong. I can't offer a suggestion though because I don't know what the underlying meaning is supposed to be.
- *"...and overcoming them"* is also wrong. At very least it may need to be something like *"... and how those difficulties were overcome."* But it may be better with a bigger fix. For example: *"The practical part presents four case studies showing the communication difficulties, and associated remedies, of selected individuals."*

Answer (score 2):

As mother of two dyslexic children, the right English rendering of what is commonly known as DSA in Italian is specific learning disorder (see http://psychcentral.com/disorders/specific-learning-disorder/), or SLD.The term specific relates to the type of disorder in that big range of difficulties affecting different skills which *should be acquired during the developmental age.
It would therefore seem incorrect alternative 2: specific school skill development disorders, because there the term *specific relates to *some school skills and it shouldn't be so.
s